# how to sort my table with count of success like statement execute in row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a query that sorts my table by the number of occurrences of a phrase in a row.

Like this:

```
select * from table where paragraph like '%im%' order by (count of success like statement execute in row) 

_________________ 
| paragraph     | 
_________________ 
|hello im vahid| 

| and im happy | with 2 (im) 
_________________
```

in this case result is

```
_________________ 
| paragraph     | 
_________________ 
|hello im vahid | 

|and im happy   | 
_________________ 
|im vahid glad  | 

|to meet u      | 
_________________
```

---

yes
Gerrat thats correct,
 every record that contains the letters "im" (in the paragraph column) ordered by descending frequency of the number of times each paragraph contains the letters "im"

```
$trimmed1= "my paragraph";
$pieces = explode(" ", trim($trimmed1));

$query = "SELECT * FROM agahi
WHERE active='2' AND  (  ";
$countp = count($pieces);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countp-1; $i++) {

$query .="  CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%".$pieces[$i]."%' OR ";
}
$query .=" CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%".$pieces[$i]."%'  " ;
$query .= ")  

ORDER BY (";

for ($i = 0; $i < $countp-1; $i++) {
$query .=
"(
CASE WHEN  CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE  '%".$piecesf[$i]."%'
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END
) + ";}

$query .= "(CASE WHEN  CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE  '%".$piecesf[$i]."%'
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END )
) DESC ";
```

this is my code, but ORDER BY not works true

this is generated code:

```
SELECT * FROM agahi WHERE active='2' AND ( CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%cd%' OR CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%dvd%' ) 

ORDER BY (
( CASE WHEN CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%cd%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
+ ( CASE WHEN CONCAT(sharh,' ',onvan,' ',kelid) LIKE '%dvd%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
) DESC
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do... Can you please explain it a little more clearly?

Comment: I *think* Vahid wants every record that contains the letters "im" (in the paragraph column) ordered by descending frequency of the number of times each paragraph contains the letters "im".  Is this correct, Vahid?  As Mike mentioned, telling us which database you're using would really help too.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table t 
inner join 
  (select tableID, numberToControlSort  
  from [put the rest of a query that calcs a priority on each row here]) s  
on t.tableID=s.tableID 
where [put your where clause here] 
order by s.numberToControlSort
```

This will work.  Unfortunately SQLServer doesn't have a stock routine that counts the number of times a substring occurs in a string.  You could write/find a function to do that, and use that function for numberToControlSort.

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the `paragraph` value, then remove all occurrences of `'im'` from it and get the length of the resulting string. The difference between the two lengths will give you the value you could use to order the result set by:

In MySQL the query could look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE paragraph LIKE '%' + @testString + '%'
ORDER BY
  CHAR_LENGTH(paragraph) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(paragraph, @testString, ''))
```

where `@testString` is your `'im'` or any other substring you want to test `paragraph` against.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as frequency 
FROM name_table 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Some guys say to use this. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

yes yes yes
this is my answer:

SELECT 
(
CHAR_LENGTH(sharh)
 - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sharh,'cd',''))
) AS nextlenght

FROM agahi

order by nextlenght DESC